# Git Fetch Upstream in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I've added an additional `Remote` but it doesn't show up in my `Branches` window.

[image]

[image]

I performed a `git fetch upstream` from [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) and now it shows up but how do I do that in Visual Studio?

---

Background: I'm trying to perform the [Git Hub Guide: Configuring a remote for a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps once you have the clone of the repo:

1. open the repository
2. Under Team Explorer - Settings --> Click on Repository Settings
3. In the Repository Settings screen under Remotes --> Click Add --> Enter the name of the remote as "upstream" and "Fetch" value to your "original remote"

[image]

4. [image]
5. [image]

Comment: thanks but I've already added the `upstream` remote.  please see the first screenshot from above.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @iab.  FYI, you have to @ mention in the comments for these edits as I didn't get notified.